# Remove question mark from Command Prompt [Java]

Tags: java, arrays, substring, latitude-longitude

Hi there I'm trying to substring a latitude number
43° 41' N

```
 lat1 = latitude[curIndex1].substring(0, (latitude[curIndex1].indexOf("°")));


        System.out.println(lat1);
        lat1Converted = Double.parseDouble(lat1);
```

In netbeans I ran the program and when I print lat1 it says 43 the rest of the program also works fine and does what it needs to.

However when I go into command prompt I get an error because it thinks there is a question mark after 43.

When it prints lat 1 out it says 43?

Because of that I can't convert it to a double and then can't use it to find the distance between two places and it crashes.

I'm not sure why it does this.

Comment: The console is unable to render the degrees character with the current font

Comment: Yes @MadProgrammer is Correct. Can you add the font using in Netbeans to your system?

Comment: It is using Lucida Console 14 which is a font Command Prompt uses correct?

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely on the degree:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+"); // extracts numbers
Matcher m = p.matcher(latitude);
int degrees = m.find() ? Integer.parseInt(m.group()) : 0;
int minutes = m.find() ? Integer.parseInt(m.group()) : 0;
int seconds = m.find() ? Integer.parseInt(m.group()) : 0;
```